# The number of bootstraps in Random Forest (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using RandomForestRegressor in python scikit-learn.

As I know, random forest algorithm takes random bootstraps samples. But I am not sure how to set and adjust the number of bootstraps.

Is n_estimators the parameter for setting the number of bootstraps? And is there any tips for setting good value of that value?

Answer (score 0):

The sub-sample size is always the same as the original input sample size but the samples are drawn with replacement if bootstrap=True (default).
Take a look here.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html

Comment: Sorry, what I meant with 'the number of subsamples' was 'the number of random bootstraps'. I updated my question.